# How To add control from ToolBox on user control in a form

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have created a user control like below ,after adding this control on a from I want to add controls like button etc on the rectangle region from ToolBox. My User control is like this.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(FrameworkElement.Width)"  >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:.5" Value="500"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0:.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(FrameworkElement.Width)"  >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:0:.5" Value="70"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenuExtend">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="RightVMenu" >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:.5" Value="600"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MenuExtendLstView">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="RightVMenu" >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:.5" Value="740"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl" >
        <Style.Triggers >
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" >
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}">
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" >
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}">
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Fill="#FF5383D6" Height="Auto" Stretch="Fill"  Width="Auto">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M 127 287 109 287 74 264V 152 41 l 33 -20 20 0 -1e-10 0 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="GreenYellow"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to add controls from ToolBox on this control after adding control  on a form.
Here in the green Rectangle region.
Please help how to acheive this.

Thanks

Comment: you can't add one control to two places, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You mean the visual studio toolbox when you're in design mode, or some toolbox you've got in your app or what?

Comment: I want to drag controls from toolbox like button on user control after adding it on form